customtkinter. Один виджет на нескольких закладках
Пишу десктопное приложение.
Создал customtkinter.CTkTabview с 4 закладкам.
На всех 4-х закладках разная информация, но должно быть одно общее поле - customtkinter.CTkTextbox.
Т.е. в CTkTextbox будет отображаться одна и та же информация.
Какую бы из 4-х закладок не открыть, в одном и том же месте должен стоять CTkTextbox, с постоянной информацией.
Прошу помощи в реализации.
Достаточно просто совета, но и от кусочка кода не откажусь!
С уважением, Tracki!

Кажется, что самым простым и не громоздким решением будет - создание нового экземпляра TextBox при нажатии на определенную вкладку и передачи текста со старого метода в новый, вот простая реализация:
import customtkinter as ctk

win = ctk.CTk()
win.geometry("400x400")

# Tabview function
def tabviewFunc(): 
    global textbox 

    textbox.pack_forget() # Удаление с вкладки старого TextBox

    tab = tabview.get() # Получение текущей вкладки
    text = textbox.get('0.0', ctk.END) # Получение текста TextBox

    textbox = ctk.CTkTextbox(tabview.tab(tab)) # Создание нового TextBox
    textbox.pack()

    textbox.insert("0.0", text) # Передача текста в новый TextBox

# Tabview
tabview = ctk.CTkTabview(win, command = tabviewFunc)
tabview.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

tabview.add("tab 1")  
tabview.add("tab 2")  
tabview.add("tab 3")
tabview.add("tab 4")

tabview.set("tab 1")  

# Textbox 
textbox = ctk.CTkTextbox(tabview.tab("tab 1"))
textbox.pack()

win.mainloop()


Благодарю!
Именно так и реализовал, только получилось - громоздко.
Думал, что есть способ более элегантный.
Но в любом случае, спасибо!
С уважением,
Tracki.

И еще проблема - при этом способе я не могу передать цветной текст.
Скопировать - да, но текст разноцветный.
И красные "вставки - предупреждения" при копировании не передаются.
Наверное можно копировать и атрибуты текстового поля...

Хотел спросить, как именно Вы добавляете цветной текст и что имеете в виду под "вставки - предупреждения"

Кусочек кода...
self.tb_home.tag_config("red_line", foreground="red")
.....
self.tb_home.insert('end', 'Внимание, ошибка!\n', "red_line")
self.tb_home.insert('end', 'Описание ошибки: ', "red_line")
self.tb_home.insert('end', e, "red_line")
Основной текст - черного цвета.
Но если возникает ошибка - красного...

Все, разобрался!
Спасибо.
Capilot написал шикарный кусочек кода по копированию цветного текста.
